# Testing stuff that should fail in mocha. (assert without catching)

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I'm trying to test fails in mocha. I want to register a fail when this request is successful, because it shouldn't be. My problem is that when I run `assert(false)`, it seems to trigger the `catch`.

```
it('Should fail to complete this hail, because driver is not driver', (done) => {
    req(rider, '/hail/complete', {
        id: driver.id
    }).then(() => {
        assert(false);
        done();
    }).catch((err) => {
        assert.equal(1, err.error.errors.length);
        done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how promise chains work: if a `.then()` throws an exception, a subsequent `.catch()` will catch it.

Since you want to catch rejections thrown by `req()`, you can work around that by adding a rejection handler to the `.then()`. And also, since you're using Mocha, you can leverage the fact that Mocha supports promises.

All that will allow you to do this:

```
it('Should fail to complete this hail, because driver is not driver', () => {
  return req(rider, '/hail/complete', { id: driver.id }).then(() => {
    assert(false);
  }, err => {
    assert.equal(1, err.error.errors.length);
  });
});
```

Comment: just curious, do you know if express.js routes support returning promises in the same way?

Comment: @Himmators no, not out of the box, although I do know that there are various NPM packages that add promise support to Express.